# unable to return unique data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

```
Array
(
    [index] => index_db,
    [type] => data
    [size] => 10
    [from] => 0
    [body] => Array
        (
            [query] => Array
                (
                    [query_string] => Array
                        (
                            [query] => search_this_data
                            [default_operator] => AND
                            [fields] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => field1
                                    [1] => field2
                                )
                        )
               )
            [sort] => Array
                (
                    [field3_date] => Array
                        (
                            [order] => desc
                            [ignore_unmapped] => 1
                        )

                    [field4_name] => Array
                        (
                            [order] => desc
                            [ignore_unmapped] => 1
                        )

                )

            [aggs] => Array
                (
                    [unique_data] => Array
                        (
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [field] => field5
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

the above code is what iam using and the query returns all rows without considering distinct filter for field5.how to use aggregration in the query so that it should return unique data depending on the field5. apart from aggregation is there any other ways to use distinct operation in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

No you have to use aggregation. But if you only need the last (or one) document of each field5 value, you can use field5 as a key and update it instead of get dupplicate. Of course it s depends of your context...